# 8bit BPP loaded as Format32bppArgb in c#

Tags: c#, aforge

I have a TIF raw file 8 bit BPP when I  do:

```
Bitmap imag = new Bitmap(imgN)
```

then :

```
imag.PixelFormat.ToString()
```

I get Format32bppArgb,
where I should get 8 bits,

I have tried to do :

```
AForge.Imaging.Image.Clone(imag, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
```

but I get

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in
>   System.Drawing.dll Additional information: A Graphics object cannot be
>   created from an image that has an indexed pixel format.

maybe I need to load it to first to a byte array and then to a bitmap?

Comment: Nope, as it says in the exception message, The Graphics object CANNOT use indexed pixel formats. If you insist on using them then you will need to use a different graphics library.

Comment: Please have a look at [this Codeproject article and code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66550/Image-Per-Pixel-Enumeration-Pixel-Format-Conversio). It contains an alternative `ChangePixelFormat` method that might be useful to you.

Comment: I tried it, and the program reads my file as "Truecolor + Alpha (32-bit)"  and the displayed pic is black same as what I have. @AndersGustafsson

Comment: @Adrian any suggestion to free library that will help?

Comment: IrfanView display the image correctly

Comment: Do you need 8 BPP? Why not just convert them to an ARGB format?

Comment: @Adrian I have some img that this is their format (8BPP), I need to do some img processing on them, and display them in  a pictuerBox - I am not sure what "ARGB format" will do

Comment: Write your own clone function, which creates the bitmap with required pixel format, and then copies original bitmap bits to it, through Bitmap.LockBits + Marshal.Copy or CopyMemory API.

Comment: TIFF is an acronym for Thousands of Incompatible File Formats.  Tinker with the code that generates the file.

Comment: I dont have access to the code that generate the file... @AlexFarber